# Express Next() return 404 not found

Tags: javascript, express, web, routes, middleware

I'm new with express and I dont have to much idea about the error that im getting.
I have a middleware in mi app.js file to get the api information but before getting the information I'm checking if the user is logged or not. 
If the user is logged I use the next() function to redirect the user to the next middleware but I'm getting a 404 error Not found.
This is my middleware:

```
app.use('/api/advertisements',jwtAuth() ,require('./routes/api/advertisements'));
```

Code in jwtAuth();

```
module.exports = function(){ return (req, res, next) => { next(); }}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try using jwtAuth without the parentheses: `app.use('/api/advertisements',jwtAuth ,require('./routes/api/advertisements'));`

Comment: @Argee That will never work. Notice that jwtAuth is function returning another function.

Comment: doh, you're right, sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last middleware you have to return a response, otherwise it will call the next() middleware and the last middleware is, by default, an express function that returns 404.

Be sure you're returning a response (example `res.json()`) in your last middleware (`/routes/api/advertisements`).

Comment: Yes, Im returning a response using res.json() at /routes/api/advertisements, I also have a console.log at the top of the function that is not debugging, I think that after the next function is automatically going to that default middleware returning the 404.

Comment: @GonWTC Can you post the code of `routes/api/advertisements`? My fear is that `routes/api/advertisements` actually contains a function that returns another function like you did for `jwtAuth()`..

Comment: const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Advertisement = require('../../models/Advertisements');

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log("/get/advertisements");
        const ads = await Advertisement.find();
        
        res.json(ads);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});

Comment: You're not exporting the router, also I'm not sure you can pass a router to `app.use`.

Comment: I found the error, my app express version was incompatible with some modules I had installed. I just uninstall express with npm uninstall express and install express npm i express. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You're welcome don't worry, if you want to help others save time answer to your question and mark the answer as the accepted one. So people will know what the problem was :)